# Consistent row spacing in longtable of matrices

Tags: tables, spacing, matrices

I have a longtable full of matrices of various sizes, but the spacing between the rows is too small. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}}
  \toprule
  \text{Group:} & \text{Matrix:} \\
  \midrule
  Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    00001 & 00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 \\
    00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 \\
    00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 \\
    01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 \\
    10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 & 01101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{4} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0001 & 0010 & 0100 & 1000 & 2000 \\
    0010 & 0100 & 2001 & 0001 & 1000 \\
    1001 & 2110 & 0001 & 0010 & 0101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{4} \times Z_{4} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    001 & 010 & 020 & 100 & 200 \\
    021 & 001 & 211 & 010 & 100 \\
    220 & 101 & 200 & 210 & 320
  \end{bmatrix}}\\
  Z_{8} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    010 & 100 & 200 & 001 & 400 \\
    210 & 010 & 100 & 400 & 401
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{8} \times Z_{4} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 02 & 40 \\
    21 & 01 & 10 & 40 & 42
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{16} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 40 & 80 \\
    81 & 01 & 10 & 20 & 40
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{32} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & (16)
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And the (not so readable) result:
[image: Initial situation]

The first thing to try when wanting to increase row spacing is to use something like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`, so I tried that. It's inconvenient because you have to reset the `\arraystretch` for each matrix inside the table, but here the code:

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}}
  \toprule
  \text{Group:} & \text{Matrix:} \\
  \midrule
  Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    00001 & 00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 \\
    00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 \\
    00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 \\
    01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 \\
    10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 & 01101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{4} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0001 & 0010 & 0100 & 1000 & 2000 \\
    0010 & 0100 & 2001 & 0001 & 1000 \\
    1001 & 2110 & 0001 & 0010 & 0101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{4} \times Z_{4} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    001 & 010 & 020 & 100 & 200 \\
    021 & 001 & 211 & 010 & 100 \\
    220 & 101 & 200 & 210 & 320
  \end{bmatrix}}\\
  Z_{8} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    010 & 100 & 200 & 001 & 400 \\
    210 & 010 & 100 & 400 & 401
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{8} \times Z_{4} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 02 & 40 \\
    21 & 01 & 10 & 40 & 42
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{16} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 40 & 80 \\
    81 & 01 & 10 & 20 & 40
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  Z_{32} & {\small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & (16)
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}}
```

However, the result still looks awful:
[image: First try]

Another solution is to add optional extra spacing at each `\\`, such as `\\[1em]`. I won't repeat the code here, but the result also doesn't look good at all:
[image: Second try]

Does anyone has any suggestions as to how to make this table look good?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does the tabular material (in your real document) span more than a page? If not, one could save a lot of overhead by switching to a "regular" `table`/`array` setup.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the observation, but the table does indeed span more than a page in my actual document. This is just the section for groups of order 2^5 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're loading the `booktabs` package, you might as well use that package's `\addlinespace` macro to insert a satisfying, i.e., constant amount of vertical whitespace between the rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} L >{\small}L @{}}
  \toprule
  \text{Group} & \text{\normalsize Matrix} \\
  \midrule
  \endhead

  \bottomrule
  \endfoot

  Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    00001 & 00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 \\
    00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 \\
    00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 \\
    01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 \\
    10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 & 01101
  \end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
  Z_{4} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0001 & 0010 & 0100 & 1000 & 2000 \\
    0010 & 0100 & 2001 & 0001 & 1000 \\
    1001 & 2110 & 0001 & 0010 & 0101
  \end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
  Z_{4} \times Z_{4} \times Z_{2} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    001 & 010 & 020 & 100 & 200 \\
    021 & 001 & 211 & 010 & 100 \\
    220 & 101 & 200 & 210 & 320
  \end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
  Z_{8} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    010 & 100 & 200 & 001 & 400 \\
    210 & 010 & 100 & 400 & 401
  \end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
  Z_{8} \times Z_{4} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 02 & 40 \\
    21 & 01 & 10 & 40 & 42
  \end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
  Z_{16} \times Z_{2} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 40 & 80 \\
    81 & 01 & 10 & 20 & 40
  \end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
  Z_{32} & 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & (16)
  \end{bmatrix} \\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an elegant answer but a workaround to make the matrices equidistant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}}
  \toprule
  \text{Group:} & \text{Matrix:} \\
  \midrule
  \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    00001 & 00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 \\
    00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 \\
    00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 \\
    01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 \\
    10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 & 01101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  \mathbbm{Z}_{4} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} & {\small
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0001 & 0010 & 0100 & 1000 & 2000 \\
    0010 & 0100 & 2001 & 0001 & 1000 \\
    1001 & 2110 & 0001 & 0010 & 0101
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}~\\ ~\\ ~\\ ~\end{bmatrix}}}\\
  \mathbbm{Z}_{4} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{4} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    001 & 010 & 020 & 100 & 200 \\
    021 & 001 & 211 & 010 & 100 \\
    220 & 101 & 200 & 210 & 320
  \end{bmatrix}}\\
  \mathbbm{Z}_{8} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    010 & 100 & 200 & 001 & 400 \\
    210 & 010 & 100 & 400 & 401
  \end{bmatrix}
  \vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}~\\ ~\\ ~\end{bmatrix}}}   \\
  \mathbbm{Z}_{8} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{4} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 02 & 40 \\
    21 & 01 & 10 & 40 & 42
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  \mathbbm{Z}_{16} \times \mathbbm{Z}_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 40 & 80 \\
    81 & 01 & 10 & 20 & 40
  \end{bmatrix}
  \vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}~\\ ~\\ ~\end{bmatrix}}} \\
  \mathbbm{Z}_{32} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & (16)
  \end{bmatrix}} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And I am also surprised to learn that `\\[2em]` produces matrices that are separated by different vertical distances.

Answer (score 1):

Change every `\end{bmatrix}} \\` to `\end{bmatrix}} \\\\`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}}
  \toprule
  \text{Group:} & \text{Matrix:} \\
  \midrule
  Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    00001 & 00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 \\
    00010 & 00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 \\
    00100 & 01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 \\
    01000 & 10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 \\
    10000 & 00101 & 01010 & 10100 & 01101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\\\
  Z_{4} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0001 & 0010 & 0100 & 1000 & 2000 \\
    0010 & 0100 & 2001 & 0001 & 1000 \\
    1001 & 2110 & 0001 & 0010 & 0101
  \end{bmatrix}} \\\\
  Z_{4} \times Z_{4} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    001 & 010 & 020 & 100 & 200 \\
    021 & 001 & 211 & 010 & 100 \\
    220 & 101 & 200 & 210 & 320
  \end{bmatrix}}\\\\
  Z_{8} \times Z_{2} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    010 & 100 & 200 & 001 & 400 \\
    210 & 010 & 100 & 400 & 401
  \end{bmatrix}} \\\\
  Z_{8} \times Z_{4} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 02 & 40 \\
    21 & 01 & 10 & 40 & 42
  \end{bmatrix}} \\\\
  Z_{16} \times Z_{2} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    01 & 10 & 20 & 40 & 80 \\
    81 & 01 & 10 & 20 & 40
  \end{bmatrix}} \\\\
  Z_{32} & {\small
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & (16)
  \end{bmatrix}} \\\\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the gap is too big, then instead change it to `\end{bmatrix}} \\\\[-5pt]` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well! I just accepted the other answer because I thought `\addlinespace` is a little more elegant and gives the right amount of spacing. Would use your way if I didn't use the `booktabs` package though.